# Parsing JSONArray response in AJAX

Tags: ajax

For the sake of keeping this question limited, here is an example from W3Schools that I extended to give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS

```
var objA = [
    { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},
    { "name2":"John2", "age2":302, "city2":"New York2"}
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = objA.name;
```

This prints undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

After review... I have this now...

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

for(var i=0;i < objA.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += objA[i]["name"];
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += objA[i]["name"];
}
```

if I leave the =+ in, it prints both JohnJohn2 in both p tags. If I remove the +, it prints just John2 in both tags. The first p tag should print john, and the second should print john2

https://jsfiddle.net/gs4zdupn/

Comment: Try like this objA[0].name

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
objA.name
```

You do

```
objA[0][“name”]
```

Comment: what is i have multiple without knowing what index im on? how is a loop done in js?

Answer (score 1):

For loop is like so

```
for(var i=0;i < objA.length;I++){
//whatever you want like objA[i]
}
```

Comment: thanks. cant add comment? its not adding both into demo. if I do += it adds both, but not in the way Im looking for. Im bascially taking a response and fulling in a bootstrap table.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is a placeholder for your code. Don’t take it literally.

Answer (score 0):

First let’s start from the beginning. Your JSON is in an array. So you don’t need name and name2. Just name it “name” for both.

```
var objA = [
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},
{ "name":"John2", "age":302, "city":"New York2"}
];
```

Then for your for loop do this

```
for(var i=0;i < objA.length;i++){
document.getElementById("demo"+(i+1) ).innerHTML += objA[i]["name"];
document.getElementById("demo"+(i+1)).innerHTML += objA[i]["name"];
}
```

Remember to rename your p tag id’s as such

```
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: this didnt work. look at my jsfiddle... play around with it if u want.